# On behalf of token issue (AADSTS50013: Assertion contains an invalid signature)

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, adal, azure-ad-msal, cortana-skills-kit

I'm getting an error (mentioned below) when I'm trying to use Cortana Bot user token (which is a Graph token) to generate an "on-behalf-of" token to another consuming Web API application using `ClientAssertionCertificate` / `ClientCredential` targeted to another consuming Web API by passing its `AppId` as `ResourceId` and `userAssertion` generated by using Cortana Bot user token.

When checked our Bot AAD settings it is configured with other consuming Web API (API B) as valid application along with Graph application. Do we need to do any additional setting in AAD to get this on-behalf-of token?

```
AADSTS50013: Assertion contains an invalid signature. 
[Reason - The provided signature value did not match the expected signature value., 
    Thumbprint of key used by client: '9DB0B05B5D70DD7901FB151A5F029148B8CC1C64', 
    Found key 'Start=11/11/2018 00:00:00, 
    End=11/11/2020 00:00:00'
]
Trace ID: a440869f-b8f5-4d87-ba1a-6bd8dd7ba200
Correlation ID: 651e1fa8-2069-4489-a687-e68e5206e193
Timestamp: 2019-01-02 07:14:45Z
```

Following is the flow and Sample code how we are trying to get an on-behalf-of token for other consuming Web API (API B).

Flow Steps:

1. Cortana asks for user Sign-in
2. User Sign-in to Cortana
3. Cortana sends this user token (generated targeting to use https://graph.microsoft.com as Audience) to Microsoft Bot Framework API
4. Microsoft Bot Framework API validates and wants to consume this token for calling other Web API (which is called API B).
5. As this Cortana user token cannot be used directly, it needs to be generated as an on-behalf-of token to API B from Microsoft Bot Framework API.
6. Following is the code sample used to generate an on-behalf-of token from Microsoft Bot Framework API:

   ```
   public async Task<string> GetOnBehalfOfTokenAsync(string authority, string resource, string scope = "", string token = "") 
   {
       AuthenticationResult output;
       var clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["API-B-ClientId"];

       // Read certificate which can be used for getting token to API B using ClientAssertionCertificate
       // GetCert() is used to get the Certificate based on Thumbprint configured in Web.config file.
       var certificate = this.GetCert();

       // 'authority' is https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant id}
       var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
       var cllientCertificateCredential = new ClientAssertionCertificate(clientId, certificate);

       // 'token' is the user token which was received from Cortana.
       var userAssertion = (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(token)) ?
           new UserAssertion(token, "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer", 
               TokenHelper.ExtractUserInfoFromAuthToken(token, "upn")) : null;
       try 
       {
           // 'resource' is the Resource Id of API B
           // if UserAssertion is null then get token with ClientAssertionCertificate else get 
           // on-behalf-of token using UserAssertion and ClientAssertionCertificate
           if (userAssertion == null) 
           {
               output = await authContext
                   .AcquireTokenAsync(resource, cllientCertificateCredential)
                   .ConfigureAwait(false);
           }   
           else 
           {
               output = await authContext
                   .AcquireTokenAsync(resource, cllientCertificateCredential, userAssertion)
                   .ConfigureAwait(false);
           }
       } 
       catch (Exception ex) 
       {
           logger.log("Error acquiring the AAD authentication token", ex);
       }

       return output.AccessToken;
   }
   ```
7. Getting an exception which was mentioned above at this step:

   ```
   output = await authContext
      .AcquireTokenAsync(resource, cllientCertificateCredential, userAssertion)
       .ConfigureAwait(false);
   ```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I strongly recommend reading ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some tips on getting started. Your question, as it stands today, doesn't include any code showing what your app is doing or what solutions you've tried so far.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow - given the reference chart here, you are saying you get an invalid signature on API B call when you pass Auth Bearer with the return access token?  Please add the calling URL and headers.

Comment: @Micromuncher, your understanding is correct that we want to pass the on-behalf-of token to API B through Auth Bearer. But we are getting above mentioned error when trying to generate on-behalf-of token  from token which was generated for API A to API B using Microsoft.IdentityModel .Net SDK libraries.

Comment: @Marc LaFleur, I've added the additional information which you are looking out from the description...

Comment: Did you try common as the tenant?  http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/08/26/the-common-endpoint-walks-like-a-tenant-talks-like-a-tenant-but-is-not-a-tenant/

Comment: @Micromuncher, I tried changing tenant to 'common', but still I'm getting same error  "Assertion contains an invalid signature."

Comment: Its interesting that you're extracting the resource ID, because in the oauth2 world and microsoft's converged end point (aadv2), you should not need to do this. Are you mixing aadv1 and aadv2 requests?

Comment: @Micromuncher, yes your understanding is correct we are mixing AADv1 (token received from Cortana is generated with AAD v1) with AAD v2 (token requested by API B).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could able to resolve this issue by configuring our dependent custom API (API B) "user_impersonation" scope to Cortana channel configuration to our Bot. With this configuration change, we do not need to generate On-Behalf-Of token to API B from our Microsoft Bot application.

Thanks to all who has supported to provide solutions for this thread...

Answer (score 3):

My understanding is: first you get user token from your Cortana access ms graph API; and then you want to use the user token to generate the OBO token in Microsoft Bot Framework API; final, you want to use the OBO token to access API B from Microsoft Bot Framework API.

You want to get OBO token in Microsoft Bot Framework API, you should use the API id and the secret, for this, I have never tried this.

On my side, I use v1 endpoint, I create two API (API A and B) and my flow is: 
First, my app requests token1 for API A;

[image]
Next, use the token1 to request OBO token2 for API B from API A;

[image]

Final, use the OBO token2 to request OBO token3 for aad graph API from API B.

[image]

For the OBO in v1 endpoint, please read [link1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow).

For the OBO in v2 endpoint, please read [link2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow).

Comment: @venu madhav, if there is anything update, please let me know, thanks.

Comment: @ SunnySun, thanks for your reply. In your above provided flow you are generating the tokens for both API A and B (hoping that these two API are configured to same AAD App). But in our case, we get the token from Cortana which we need to use for generating a OBO token for API B by using Certificate Credentials OR Client Secret for our Bot AAD App where API B is configured with Authorization permissions).