# How to get access token to call MS Graph on behalf of a user in the console app using MSAL?

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

I have a SPA application that communicates with my backend Web API using AAD v2 authentication. Now I'm developing a console app to call Microsoft Graph on behalf of the user signed into the SPA app.

I have a valid access token of the user (used to call backend Web API). I want to use this access token to request a new token for accessing MS Graph.

Here is the code of the console app for requesting a new access token with MS Graph scopes using MSAL.NET:

```
string clientId = "<clientId>";
string clientSecret = "<clientSecret>";
string accessToken = "<validAccessTokenForWebApi>";
string assertionType = "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer";
string[] scopes = new string[] { "User.Read", "Mail.Send" };
string graphAccessToken = null;

try
{
    var app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                .Create(clientId).WithClientSecret(clientSecret).Build();

    var userAssertion = new UserAssertion(accessToken, assertionType);

    var result = app.AcquireTokenOnBehalfOf(scopes, userAssertion)
                    .ExecuteAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

    graphAccessToken = result.AccessToken;
}
catch (MsalServiceException ex)
{
    throw;
}
```

But when I call `app.AcquireTokenOnBehalfOf()` I get an exception:

> AADSTS50013: Assertion failed signature validation. [Reason - The provided signature value did not match the expected signature value., Thumbprint of key used by client: 'BB839F3453C7C04068B078EDADAB8E6D5F382E76', Found key 'Start=06/04/2019 00:00:00, End=06/04/2021 00:00:00']

What is the reason? What is the right way of getting access token on behalf of a user?

**UPDATE - why do I need console app?**

I could call Graph API directly from my backend API, but some actions may be delayed by the user (e.g. send mail using Graph API after 30 minutes). That is why I need to do this using the console app that runs on schedule.

Comment: You might have a problem with your app registrations on Azure Portal. Take a look at [this sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-aspnet-webapi-onbehalfof) as a reference on how to configure them. Also, this answer might be relevant to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54008866/on-behalf-of-token-issue-aadsts50013-assertion-contains-an-invalid-signature

Comment: You may want to provide the raw request (remove secrets) resulting from the failing call. The error msg seems to point to invalid access token format.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54008866/on-behalf-of-token-issue-aadsts50013-assertion-contains-an-invalid-signature

Comment: @FIL  I have updated my answer to tell you how to call Graph API. Please check it.

Comment: @FIL I check your code. You seem that you did not provide authority endpoint.

Comment: @Jim authority does not matter. I'm still getting AADSTS50013 error.

Comment: Could you tell me how you get access token for web api?

Comment: @FIL Could you tell me the detailed error message of AADSTS50013  after you try my latest answer?

Comment: @FIL Any update?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use [OAuth 2.0 On-Behalf-Of flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow), I think you do not need to develop a console application to call graph api. You can directly use your backend Web API application to acquire access token then call Microsoft Graph. According to my understanding, you just do these steps

1. Sign-in the user in the client application
2. Acquire a token to the Web API (TodoListService) and call
   it.
3. The Web API then calls another downstream Web API (The Microsoft
   Graph).

[image]

For more details, please refer to the [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-aspnet-webapi-onbehalfof).

Regarding how to get access token with on behalf flow in the console application, The detailed steps are as below.

**Register the web api app**

1. [Register APP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-configure-app-access-web-apis)
2. Create Client secrets
3. [Configure  permissions to access Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-configure-app-access-web-apis)
4. [Configure an application to expose web APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-configure-app-expose-web-apis)(Add scope for the api)

**Register the SAP app**

5. [Register APP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-configure-app-access-web-apis)
6. Create Client secrets
7. [Configure  permissions to access web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-configure-app-access-web-apis)

**Configure known client applications for web API application**

1. In the Azure portal, navigate to your Web api
   app registration and click on the Manifest section.
2. Find the property knownClientApplications and add the Client IDs of the SAP applications

**Get access token to call web api**

```
   GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
?scope=<you web api scope> openid
    &redirect_uri=<your sap app redirect url>
    &nonce=test123
    &client_id=<you sap app client id>
    &response_type=id_token token
```

**get access token with on behalf flow**

REST API

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer
&client_id=<you web api client id>
&assertion=<you acess token you get in above steps>
&client_secret=<you app secret> 
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/user.read
&requested_token_use=on_behalf_of
```

MSAL.net Code

```
string[] scopes = { "user.read" };
            string accesstoken = "";

            string appKey = "yor web api client secret";
            string clientId = "your web api application id";

            var app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
              .WithClientSecret(appKey)
              .Build();
            UserAssertion userAssertion = new UserAssertion(accesstoken, 
 "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer");
            var result = app.AcquireTokenOnBehalfOf(scopes, userAssertion).ExecuteAsync().Result;
            Console.WriteLine(result.AccessToken);
```

Comment: I could call Graph API directly from my backend API, but some actions may be delayed by the user (e.g. send mail using Graph API after 30 minutes). That is why I need to do this using the console app that runs on schedule.

Comment: @FIL Thanks for your response. I have updated my answer to tell you how to call Graph API. Please check it.

Comment: The question is not about calling Graph API but how to get a valid access token. Btw. I use [Microsoft Graph .NET Client Library](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet) to access Graph API.

Comment: @FIL I have updated my code to tell you how to get an access token with on behalf flow. Besides, could you tell me which is access token you want to know how to get?

Comment: I tried to get access token with your code, still getting AADSTS50013 error. I want to get an access token to call Graph API as a user.

Comment: @FIL could you please provide the access token for web api？

Comment: you mean complete valid access token returned by Azure AD?

Comment: @FIL Ok. I see. Could you tell me how you get access token for web api?

Comment: My SPA app acquired an access token from Azure AD, just like the steps 1 & 2 in your answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197974/discussion-between-jim-and-fil).